# Can google crawl my website if I change link urls with javascript on the front end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-search

I am building a website with buttons. When a user clicks a button, the URLs of other links and buttons are changed with jQuery.

Would Google be able to crawl my site effectively, or would I have to use forms?

Comment: Can I use your website with javascript disabled? Otherwise the answer will always be 'no, google can't crawl that'.

Comment: Yes, google will crawl it, however, the action that happens after the button was clicked will not affect the crawling, the crawler will see the original version of the page. The above comment is not completely correct, the google crawler will execute javascript and read the resulting page, it just will not interact with the page (aside from "clicking" on anchor tags with an href)

Comment: Take a look at [Google's guide to AJAX Crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

Comment: and here's a more recent article, though it doesn't go into much detail: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html the key point is that the crawler does pull in and execute javascript, but don't expect it to click on your buttons. To be sure, use the fetch as googlebot feature.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect Google crawlers to click all your buttons and discover every URL you want to be searchable. You CAN, however, submit a sitemap to google that tells them explicitly how your site is organized.

Search around online for Google webmaster tools. I'm not an expert on it, but I suspect you'll find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Google can navigate through your hrefs, but it won't crawl dynamically loaded content resulting from button clicks.

Here's a link that explains how to create/submit a sitemap through Google. This is your best bet for making sure you cover all your bases: https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en